# Search returns an empty array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

```
router.get('/direcciones', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.user._id
    let id2 = id.toString()
    await Dir.find({
        uid: {
            $elemMatch: { _id: id2}
        }
        },  async (err, dir) => {
            console.log(dir);
            res.render('direcciones', {dir: dir, id: id})
    });
});
```

When I search by ID I don't get any results.

```
_id:ObjectId("5ed71f27e391a332b8f4aea8")
active:true
dir:"asdasd, Pariahuanca, Los Olivos, Peru"
dirname:"aeds"
uid:Object
   _id:ObjectId("5ed6ef2251c32527a03bf1ca")
__v:0
```

This is the Schema.

What should I do?

Comment: did you try `Dir.find({ "uid._id": id2 })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$elemMatch` operators are used to match inside an array. In your case, it looks like an object, not an array so can use dot notation to match field in a embedded document. `uuid._id` is of type `ObjectId`, so need to cast it to `ObjectId` before querying. Also, you don't need to use callback when using `await`

```
try {
  const result = await Dir.find({ "uuid._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id2) });
  // handle response
} catch (err) {
  // handle failure response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that you convert your `_id`, that is already coming as string, to string with `.toString()`. You should convert it to an ObjectId if your field is an Object Id in your database.

```
id2 = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id);
```